# Blazor + SQLTableDependency + SignalR: Notify specific groups from OnChange event

Tags: c#, .net-core, signalr, blazor, signalr-hub

I have a Blazor application that uses SQLTableDependency to detect database changes, then notify all clients about the change via SignalR. This works but I need a way to be able to detect changes and only notify specific SignalR groups. Because SQLTableDependency doesn't care about who inserted, altered, or deleted a record in the database, I am not sure how to know which group to send the update too. Please see below for more details about my app and what i'm trying to accomplish.

For each customer we setup a new organization. An organization has its own list of assets, and can have multiple users.

**Organization.cs**

```
    public class Organization
    {
    public int OrganizationId { get; set; }

    public string OrganizationName { get; set; }

    public List<Asset> Assets { get; set; }

    public List<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }

    public bool IsDisabled { get; set; }

   }
```

**Asset.cs**

```
public class Asset
{
    public int AssetId { get; set; }

    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }

    public int OrganizationId { get; set; }

    public virtual Organization Organization { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
}
```

ApplicationUser.cs

```
 public class ApplicationUser 
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public int OrganizationId { get; set; }

    public virtual Organization Organization { get; set; }

    public List<Connection> Connections { get; set; }

    public string Timezone { get; set; }

}
```

Connection.cs - I am storing each SignalR Connection in the database.

```
    public class Connection
    {
    public string ConnectionId { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public bool Connected { get; set; }

    public string Group { get; set; }

    public DateTime ConnectionTime { get; set; }

    }
```

AssetService.cs

```
    public class AssetService : IAssetService
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

    public AssetService(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
    }
  
         public async Task<Asset> AddAssetAsync(Asset asset, string currentUserName)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
            {
                var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<DataContext>();

                if (asset.Device != null)
                {
                    db.Entry(asset.Device).State = EntityState.Modified;
                }
                asset.DateAdded = DateTime.UtcNow;
                await db.Assets.AddAsync(asset);
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return asset;
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
           throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

AssetHub.cs - SignalR Hub

```
 public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

    public ChatHub(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
    }

    public async Task SendAssetToGroup(string userName, string location, Asset asset)
    {

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userName))
        {
            var user = await _userManager.Users.Include(x => x.Connections).SingleAsync(x => x.UserName == userName);

            if (user != null)
            {
                var group = $"{user.AccountId}-{location}";

                await Clients.Group(group).SendAsync("AssetUpdate", user.Email, asset);
            }
        }
    }

    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        var httpContext = Context.GetHttpContext();
        var location = httpContext.Request.Query["location"];

        using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userName))
            {

                var user = await db.Users.Include(x => x.Connections).SingleAsync(x => x.UserName == httpContext.User.Identity.Name);

                if (user != null)
                {
                    var group = $"{user.OrganizationId}-{location}";
                    var connection = new Connection { Connected = true, ConnectionId = Context.ConnectionId, Group = group, UserName = user.UserName };

                    await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(connection.ConnectionId, group);

                    user.Connections.Add(connection);

                    db.Users.Update(user);
                }
            }
           
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        await base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }

    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Context.ConnectionId))
        {
            using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
            {
                var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();

                var connection = await db.Connections.Where(x => x.ConnectionId == 
                Context.ConnectionId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

                if (connection != null)
                {
                    await Groups.RemoveFromGroupAsync(connection.ConnectionId, connection.Group);
                    db.Connections.Remove(connection);
                    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
            }
        }

        await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }
}
```

AssetTableChangeService.cs - Here is where I need help. When SQLTableDependency detects a change to the Assets table, I need to be able to call the SendAssetToGroup Method in the AssetHub. Since users are apart of organizations, I don't want to push the update out to all organizations, I only want to send the update only to users that are apart of the specific organization group.

```
 public class AssetTableChangeService : IAssetTableChangeService
{
    private const string TableName = "Assets";
    private SqlTableDependency<Asset> _notifier;
    private IConfiguration _configuration;

    public event AssetChangeDelegate OnAssetChanged;

    public StockTableChangeService(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;

        // SqlTableDependency will trigger an event 
        // for any record change on monitored table  
        _notifier = new SqlTableDependency<Asset>(
             _configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
             TableName);
        _notifier.OnChanged += AssetChanged;
        _notifier.Start();
    }

    private void AssetChanged(object sender, RecordChangedEventArgs<Asset> e)
    {

        OnAssetChanged.Invoke(this, new AssetChangeEventArgs(e.Entity, e.EntityOldValues));
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _notifier.Stop();
        _notifier.Dispose();
    }
```

So the flow should look like this.

1. The user logs in - establishing a connection through SignalR
2. The connection information is stored in the database.
3. The connection is added to a SignalR group based on what page the user is connecting from and the OrganizationId.
4. User creates a new Asset from the UI.
5. The AddAsset method is called in the Asset Service.
6. The Asset gets inserted into the database.
7. The SQLTableDependency detects the change and then calls the AssetChanged handler method.
8. The AssetChanged handler method calls the OnAssetChanged event.
9. The AssetHub needs to subscribe to the OnAssetChanged event.
10. When the OnAssetChanged event is fired, a handler method in the AssetHub needs to call the SendAssetToGroup Method.
11. When user navigates from the Assets page to another, the SignalR connection is removed from the database, and the connection is removed from the group.

I have everything working up until steps 9 and 10. Is there anyway to make this possible since SQLTableDependency doesn't care about who made the change, so I have no way of looking up the connection group in which the update needs to be pushed too. Any ideas?

Comment: You don't mention if this is Blazor-ServerSide or Blazor-WASM  - that's quite important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the UI is working with a class for example called : Student

The UI component joins a group called "Student" or "BlahNamespace.Student".
If its a list just the name, if its an entity join the both the name and another group with the ID as a string concatenated
"BlahNamespace.Student:201" In your case you could append the the organization's name as well for finer grain if the db knows this from the entity.

The server can notify the groups as needed depending on the operation.

I inject the hub into the API controller to achieve this.

Personally I would not use the signalr service to transfer the data, keep it light weight, just "signal" the change. The client can then decide how to deal with that. That way the data can be only accessed one way via the API with all the configured security.

Comment: When our client connects to the SignalR hub, it passes a query string that contains the users location within the app. So for instance, if the user was on the Assets component. It would pass "Assets" as the location. The OnConnectedAsync() method then concatenates a string called group which is OrganizationId + "-" + location. Then adds the connection to that group. Are you saying to skip the SQLTableDependency, and call the event from the AddAsset method? The event would then tell SignalR to signal all clients to pull the updated record? I just want to be sure i'm on the same page as you?

Comment: @JaronJohnson I let each component connect to the hub, not one connection per user, but the component only joins the group it is interested in. So if the server updates an item, in that group, it broadcasts only in that group then only the users with components visible (subscribed to that group) will get the signal to update from the api if they choose too.

Comment: @JaronJohnson If a component is a list of students it would connect to my SyncHub and join the group "Students".  If the component represents an item it would join the group "Students:WhateverIdItHas". 

The server when it updates a student then broadcasts only in the "Students" group and in the "Students:WhateverIDItHas" group on the SyncHub. That way only components subscribed to the groups see the broadcast.

Comment: In your case a component displaying multiple Assets could use the group name of $"{OrganizationId}:Assets".
If its displaying an individual Asset the name $"Assets:{AssetId}".

Comment: Okay, this makes sense, i'll do some testing and see if I can make this work. i'll let you know! Thank you!